# understanding wp_next_scheduled

Tags: php, hooks, wp-cron

I have a function that I've been attempting to get to work with wp_schedule_event. The function sends a notification to the admin. I see the event get added to the wp cron event list, but it never runs the function.

Function as follows:

```php
<?php

function send_booking_expiration_notification(){
  // do woocomerce booking stuff... then send email.
 wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}

// Schedule the send_booking_expiration_notification() function to run daily at midnight
if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'send_booking_expiration_hook' ) ) {
    wp_schedule_event( strtotime( '12pm' ), 'hourly', 'send_booking_expiration_hook' );
}
add_action( 'send_booking_expiration_hook', 'send_booking_expiration_notification' );

?>
```

Am I misunderstanding scope or hooks. I've added the add_action above the function and still no dice. I can call the function and the have confirmed the function works and send email, but something with the cron isn't working.

Comment: Note... I know this is set to hourly, did this for testing. But this will be reverted back to daily and send a notification at 7am EST daily.

Comment: it's very possible that it _is_ running but either crashing, or the email is being discarded once it leaves the server ( especially if you're on a shared server or sending lots of emails ), note that generally it's not a great idea to run code in the root of a file that isn't in a hook unless it's a theme template outputting HTML, Vancoders answer may well be the solution here

Comment: this function is within the functions.php of the theme directory.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably attempting to add this too early. Wait for `init`.

```
add_action(
    'init',
    function () {
        if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'send_booking_expiration_hook' ) ) {
            wp_schedule_event( strtotime( '12pm' ), 'hourly', 'send_booking_expiration_hook' );
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: I've added this into the themes functions.php  does this still need to wait for init. I have also confirmed this is added to the event list using wp cli i.e the wp cron event list.

| send_booking_expiration_hook | 2022-12-15 17:00:00 | 47 minutes 43 seconds | 1 hour |

Comment: the time passes and never get anything

Comment: how are you testing it? And how are you confirming that it ran? If you tested the code _as is_ you would need to wait until 12pm noon, so you couldn't possibly have checked this in the 38 minutes since the answer was written

Comment: A good trick I use whenever I implement scheduled events is that I record the time the CRON last ran:  `$current_time = date( 'F j, Y, g:i a' );` to capture the time, then `update_option( 'sendbooking_last', $current_time );`

With that, you can always do a search of your `wp_options` table for `sendbooking_last` and see whether or not the value is updating every hour.